# WebSphere Portal 6.1 + WAS 6.1 + Myfaces Portlet Bridge

Tags: websphere, portlet, portal, myfaces, websphere-portal

Does anyone know how to replace the IBM JSF Portlet Bridge with Myfaces Portlet Bridge 2.0? I want to set up a small local testing environment. Pluto + Tomcat + Myfaces Portlet Bridge.
My Portlets are on JSF 1.1, but it should be possible to use JSF 1.2 Implementation!?
Target is that a developed portlet(some old portlets use ibm jsf extended components) work on websphere portal and pluto without changes. I managed with maven profiles to get a small portlet with ibm jsf components to work in pluto, but i dont get it to work in websphere portal...
Does anyone have experiences with that issue?